# Create image heavy pdf's with php

Tags: php, pdf

What is the best way to create image heavy pdf's (dynamicly) with php?
Doing this in the browser can timeout the request.

Is it possible to handly this on the server and show the result after processing?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Websocket to send portions of the PDF and assemble them via JavaScript? I cannot tell you how to display the PDF from JavaScript, but I’m sure it is possible. Check out [socket.io](http://socket.io).

Answer (score 0):

it's possible : you have to run your code in command line (this may be triggered by a web page though)

You may need to setup a queue to process files one by one if you know there are multiple files to create.

Comment: This is exactly what I do in one of my web apps. If you already have a PHP script (and I assume you do since you know it times out in the browser), you can modify it for command-line execution and then do a "fork" using code like the following: `exec('php pdf_gen.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`